# Good parser to parse large XML file and handling the parsed data in Swift

Tags: swift, core-data, xml-parsing, ios10

My question is in two folds - the first part is choosing the appropriate XML parser and the second part is a question about a proper way to handle the parsed data.

I need to parse two XML files from the web. One file contains ~200K lines and the other one contains ~10K lines. The data is used in populating three TableViewControllers. I have been researching on XML parsers and have read several posts on StackOverflow, but I'm still confused about which one to choose.My research led me to believe that either SWXMLHash or AEXML is suitable for my situation. SWXMLHash seems to be a good choice for parsing large XML file (with lazy loading option) but I need to use Alamofire since it can't handle URL request. But when I look at Alamofire examples, I'm under the impression that the requested file is returned as a whole through callback function call. If I understand correctly, that means the whole file is stored in memory. (So what's the point of lazy loading of SWXMLHash if the file is already in memory?) So I look into AEXML examples, but seems that it is not even async library and it also loads the data into memory. So which library should I be looking into for parsing those XML files?

One approach I thought of on handling parsed data is to store them in core data and query the core data when I need to populate the TableViewControllers. The core data needs to be updated on daily basis since the XML files on the server are updated daily. If the user does not have data with today's datestamp, I'll just drop the existing tables, download the new XML files, parsed them and create two new tables with that parsed data. Does that approach efficient/reliable?

UPDATE :

I was wrong about AlamoFire. It does have a method that downloads the file and stored it on the disk in addition to those methods that return data in the response variable. So parsing, I decide to use combination of SWXMLHash and AlamoFire.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If:

- This data does not always need to be updated, only on occasion.
- Core data can [scale effectively](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/CoreData/Performance.html) to a very large number of small entries.

Then:

- Use whichever XMLParser is fastest with large data sets.
- Parse the downloaded data, and store the parsed data into Core Data (possibly create new entries per XML key:value pair).
- After the initial download of the XML file, only check the [status code](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_HTTP_status_codes) on subsequent accesses (304 means that nothing has changed).
- When populating the table, you can use Core Data to access the individual properties without loading the whole file into memory.

Comment: Thanks, especially for mentioning status code checking approach!. But which parser would you recommend? The two parsers I've mentioned in my post do not seem to be a good fit for my need and LIBXML2 is supposedly primitive. Then AQXL which I couldn't find good documentation.

Comment: With the caveat that I haven't actually used it, from what I can tell, SWXMLParser should suit your needs. Because you are only loading the file (either via Alamofire or URLSession) occasionally, the functional data that you are working with in your table is of a very low memory footprint. For that reason, I recommend whichever XMLParser is most usable, which, at a glance, seems to be the case for SWXMLParser.

Comment: I was wrong about Alamofire. It does have an option to download the whole file and stored it on the disk in addition to returning as a response variable. From that, I can feed the data into SWXMLParser. Thanks for all the suggestions!

Comment: P.S I will leave the question open for few more hours just to see if anyone has interesting approach to dealing with the data. I will mark yours as a correct after that.